# Nginx + php5.2 fpm 502 errors

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I've found 2 kinds of 502 errors in my server:

```
connection reset by peer, it happens as request_time reach to 10s.
connection timeout, it happens as request_time reach to 3s.
```

Server is:

```
centos , kernel(2.6.32)
php5.2 php-fpm
nginx 1.6.3.
```

access logs outputs:

```
[28/Nov/2015:14:41:08 +0800] "GET /ben2.php HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)" "-" 3.000

[28/Nov/2015:14:41:11 +0800] "GET /ben2.php HTTP/1.1" 502 172 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)" "-" 10.000
```

error logs:

```
2015/11/28 14:41:11 [error] 12981#0: *798323 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: xx.xx.xx, request: "GET /ben2.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xx.xx.xx"

2015/11/28 14:41:08 [error] 12981#0: *798215 connect() failed (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: xx.xx.xx, request: "GET /ben2.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xx.xx.xx"
```

I've tried "request_terminate_timeout, fastcgi_connect_timeout, fastcgi_read/write_timeout", but no help.

What can I do next step ?

EDIT:
I wrote a php file that ran for 11s, no 502 error (so I think there is no limit in nginx and php).

502 Errors maybe only occure on pressure testing.

and on 502 errors the php scripts still run successfully.